# Color style is not getting applied at run time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my Razor I am doing this:

```
string style = Model.GetDateStyle(license.ExpirationDate);
<label class="control-label resultValueLabel" style=@style>@license.ExpirationDate</label>
```

From the implementation I have written for `GetDateStyle()` method if I put a break point I can see that **"color: red;"** is coming to `style` variable above. BUT it does NOT change the color of the label to red, Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the variable in quotes.

```
<label class="control-label resultValueLabel" style="@style">@license.ExpirationDate</label>
```

Comment: I originally had it that way, didn't work, then removed the double quotes, still didn't work

Comment: @Bohn, Can you share the generate HTML?

Comment: ok I went to Chrome Dev tools now, color red is there but it is stricked out. So code works, just CSS issues then.

Answer (score 1):

Razor declaration is incorrect:

```
 @{string style = Model.GetDateStyle(license.ExpirationDate);}
 <label class="control-label resultValueLabel" style="@style">@license.ExpirationDate</label>
```